# How to simulate a Webbrowser.Navigate in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, simulate

I need to send a request like using WebBrowser.Navigate (from windows forms), but, I'd like to use an iframe instead of windows forms components.

I'm trying to use WebRequest and WebResponse, but I'm having some problems to get response. I'm implement Integrated Check from SERASA, a company from Brazil. Using windows forms, that's ok.

Windows forms:

```
   String postData = string.Format("keyIntegracao={0}&key={1}&cnpj={2}&produto=      {3}&documento={4}&uf={5}", keyIntegrador, key,    cnpj, produto, documento, uf);

   System.Text.Encoding enconding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] bytePD = enconding.GetBytes(postData);

   string username = "user";
   string password = "pass";
   string url = String.Format("https://{0}:{1}@url.com.br/consulta/createRequest", username, password);

// Abertura do Componente WebBrowser

   webBrowser1.Navigate(url, "", bytePD, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Now, in webforms, I'm trying :

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

 SetBasicAuthHeader(request, username, password);

 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.ContentLength = bytePD.Length;

 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();            
 dataStream.Write(bytePD, 0, bytePD.Length);           
 dataStream.Close();

 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                       

 dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();     

 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

 string saida = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();

 frame.Attributes.Add("src", response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri);


  reader.Close();
  dataStream.Close();
  response.Close();
```

Method

```
public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
{
    string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
}
```

To redirect the response to an iframe, I'm using the url "response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri", but it does not show the response as it would be. Using windows forms, it works properly.

How could I simulate a Webbrowser.Navigate, using webforms?

thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing nuts with apples.

In desktop you should be passing your authentication to the webbrowser in some way (cookies, query string, etc) but when you put the url into an iFrame from ASP .net you did your authentication on your server, so the client will not be authenticated.

You should do the authentication process in the client side if you want him to be logged or find a way to propagate that authentication to the client.

Comment: Sorry, I never did It before. You mean I should do the authentication process when I receive the answer (response) from the request? Or when I'm sending the postData?

Comment: You cannot authenticate in your server (asp .net codebehind) and expect that a client who knows where to be authenticated. Or you authenticate in the client side (javascript) or you find a mechanism to propagate a session to the client (which will prove really hard depending on the case)